# Writing to picture which is scanned document

Tags: text-processing, image-editor, image-manipulation, ocr

I have a scanned contract and I need to change only a few names and dates in the contract.

It's easy to scan the document but impossible to ocr the document and open in *.doc format.

Is there an application that is able to reliably change the dates and names in scanned image,
so I can print it with other names and dates?

thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing would be gimp. Better would be to get the original source and edit it. Or OCR it, and then tweak it by hand. Or re-type it.